# App crashes when being resumed

Tags: windows-phone-7

My wp7 app crashes when I come back from a task such as Map, Call or Web Browser. Infact, if i lock my phone and resume it again, still it crashes. Please tell me what could be the problem and how can I remove it?

Comment: Launch application with attached debugger and tell us what is an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with you code.

1. Remove the application off the phone by starting a new emulator instance.
2. Open App.xaml.cs
3. Put a breakpoint in the method `RootFrame_NavigationFailed` and `Application_UnhandledException`
4. Now use the CallStack to find the root of the issue.

With no code posted (and in your case it could be ANYTHING in the project) you will be the best person to resolve your issue. If you can post a small reproduction on here we can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In application exit methods you probably should restore the data you dealt with last time before you quited